# Make a page horizontal on Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

I can't figure out how to make a page horizontal.

Answer (score 4):

To change a page from vertical (*portrait*) to horizontal (*landscape*):

- On your document, select **File** from the menu at the top
- Select **Page Setup**
- Select **Landscape**
- Select **OK**

Comment: This works for the whole document, not for a single page or section of the document.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to make a single page landscape, only the whole document. This workaround may help:

1. Write your content, then cut it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
2. Select **Insert** from the menu at the top, then **Drawing...**
3. Paste your content with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>
4. Click **Actions** up the top right, then **Rotate**, then **Rotate Anticlockwise by 90°**
5. Click **Save & Close**

From here you can size your "drawing" to fit the page. It may help to insert page breaks before and after using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to avoid changing the scale of the content.